# aggregating values within json data

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

**How do I sum values in a json data set?**

I'm trying to sum all values in my dataset for the field `TaxAmount`:

```
var url = "https://...........";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        console.log(data);           

    }
};
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send();
```

here's a snapshot of `data`:

[image]

If we inspect one of these items in the array returned above:

```
{
   [functions]: ,
   __proto__: { },
   AccountID: null,
   AccountUID: null,
   AgentCost: 0,
   Amount: 24.3,
   AccountsItemID: null,
   TaxAmount: 2.01
}
```

I've attempted to sum `TaxAmount` for all elements like so:

```
    var totalTaxAmount = data.reduce(function(pv, cv) {             
         pv += cv["TaxAmount"];
    }, {});
```

Perhaps I need to do a `data.forEach.reduce`?

**How do I sum values in a json data set?**

Comment: You need to return `pv` from the function passed to `reduce`.

Comment: why are we returning pv every time, rather than just returning ONCE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var arr = [
{
   AccountID: null,
   AccountUID: null,
   AgentCost: 0,
   Amount: 24.3,
   AccountsItemID: null,
   TaxAmount: 2.01
},
{
   AccountID: null,
   AccountUID: null,
   AgentCost: 0,
   Amount: 24.3,
   AccountsItemID: null,
   TaxAmount: 3.01
}
];

 var totalTaxAmount = arr.reduce(function(pv, cv) {             
         pv += cv["TaxAmount"];
         return pv;
    }, 0);
console.log(totalTaxAmount);
```

Comment: why are we returning pv every time, rather than just returning ONCE ?

Comment: @l--''''''---------''''''''''''  We need to return because after each iteration we will add the current value to our accumulator . This returned value will then be our new accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

As commented; you need to return sum of pv and cv and you need the second argument to reduce to be 0 instead of an object:

```
var totalTaxAmount = data.reduce(
  function(pv, cv) {
    /** added return and no need to change pv */return pv + cv["TaxAmount"];
  }, 
  /** changed to zero */0
);
```